# two horizontal JTable header and add separator to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jseparator

I'm working with JTable, and I want two things:

1. I would like to add another table header to my JTable, is this possible? Both of them in horizontal.
2. I want it's add a separator when the one of the attributes change its value, is this possible?

How can I do these things? See here the table as I want it.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a second header. You can also add a separator by using the setBorder() method.

```
table.add(new JScrollPane(table));
table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED,1));
```

Comment: Thank you, but how?
I try to work with Border, but It throw an error in the import java.swing.border.Border